# My App is working on the emulator but is not working on a real device

Tags: android-emulator, android

Hi I developed an android app, but I don't have an android myself to test it on :(. I sent it to a friend to test and every step of the way "things" aren't working, and we're getting lots of "forced close". What can I do to investigate, to get details off of the android device?

Also, are there any differences between the emulator and a device that I should be aware of that may be causing the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Josh

ps: I understand I'm not giving too many details, my question is more to understand how I can get details and how do I approach dealing with this problem

Answer (score 2):

One way will be to use a Crash Reporting system (included in the 2.2 SDK or you could try [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)). This will help you get access to the error log. If your friend is willing to help, you could ask him to install an application that records logs and then having him send them to you (search the Market for CatLog viewer applications).

Most probably this is happening due to an assumption that you are making, which is true in the emulator, but false in the device. There are many reasons that could cause this (screen size differences, networking code, SD card access code). You need the error log in order to get started.

Comment: thanks for your comment, am I the only one developing for an android without having a device?